# Is there way I can have drop down generating another dropdown?

Tags: android

I have created a drop down in my android application using a spinner. However the items in my spinner should have sub items. What I am trying to achieve is that when user clicks on one of the items, another drop down box is shown. (as if a spinner fanning out another spinner)

I am open to other suggestions beside a spinner if there is a better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a loot at [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

If you don't want it to be in a separate screen, you can place this into  a Dialog, and make the dialog automatically dismiss and select the sub-list item that is pressed.

Comment: This is a good suggestion except that I am looking for multilevel list. It is not just 2 levels, it is 4 levels

Comment: in this case, you should have a look at http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/